# Indexing a large file (32gb worth of file)

Tags: c++, windows, indexing, database-design

Apologies in advance as I think I need to give a background of my problem.

We have a proprietary database engine written in native c++ built for 32bit runtime, the database records are identified by their record number (basically offset in the file where a record is written) and a "unique id" (which is nothing more than -100 to LONG_MIN).

Previously the engine limits a database to only 2gb (where block of record could be a minimum size of 512bytes up to 512*(1 to 7)). This effectively limits the number of records to about 4 million.

We are indexing this 4 million records and storing the index in a hashtable (we implemented an extensible hashing for this) and works brilliantly for 2gb database. Each of the index is 24bytes each. each record's record number is indexed as well as the record's "unique id" (the indexes reside in the heap and both record number and "unique id" can point to the same index in heap). The indexes are persisted in memory and stored in the file (however only the record number based indexes are stored in file). While in memory, a 2gb database's index would consume about 95mb which still is fine in a 32bit runtime (but we limited the software to host about 7 databases per database engine for safety measure)

The problem begins when we decided to increases the size of the database from 2gb to 32gb. This effectively increased the number of records to about 64 million, which would mean the hashtable would contain 1.7gb worth of index in heap memory for a single 32gb database alone.

I ditched the in memory hashtable and wrote the index straight to a file, but I failed to consider the time it would take to search for an index in the file, considering I could not sort the indexes on demand (because write to the database happens all the time which means the indexes must be updated almost immediately). Basically I'm having problems with re-indexing, that is our software needs to check if a record exist and it does so by checking the current indexes if it resides there, but since I now changed it from in-memory to file I/O index, its now taking forever just to finish 32gb indexing (2gb indexing as I have computed it will apparently take 3 days to complete).

I then decided to store the indexes in order based on record number so I dont have to search them in file, and structure my index as such:

```
struct node {
 long recNum; // Record Number
 long uId;    // Unique Id
 long prev;
 long next;
 long rtype;
 long parent;
}
```

It works perfectly if I use recNum to determine where in file the index record is stored and retrieves it using read(...), but my problem is if the search based on "unique id".

When I do a search on the index file based on "unique id", what I'm doing essentially is loading chunks of the 1.7gb index file and checking the "unique id" until I get a hit, however this proves to be a very slow process. I attempted to create an Index of the Index so that I could loop quicker but it still is slow. Basically, there is a function in the software that will eventually check every record in the database by checking if it exist in the index first using the "unique id" query, and if this function comes up, to finish the 1.7gb index takes 4 weeks in my calculation if I implement a file based index query and write.

So I guess what 'm trying to ask is, when dealing with large databases (such as 30gb worth of database) persisting the indexes in memory in a 32bit runtime probably isn't an option due to limited resource, so how does one implement a file based index or hashtable with out sacrificing time (at least not so much that its impractical).

Comment: None of the historic background is necessary to explain your issue. Unfortunately, you failed to describe the real problem with enough detail to produce a solution.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to search in different orders. On other databases I've used this is done by adding a secondary index for the most common search orders (until you reach "fast enough" for all queries).

Comment: again apologies, I edited the last two paragraph of my post in an attempt to describe the problem

Comment: You might find that a different on-disk data-structure (such as a B-Tree) works better for you than a hash table does.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner, That was my intention when I moved the in-memory hashtable to file, I can write the records in file already sorted by calculating the record number and the size of my struct, however, a "unique id" can also point to the same record but I cant order the indexes based on "unique id" as its already ordered by record number.

Comment: Just as a thought experiment---if your software wrote/maintained two database files, one indexed by "record number" and the other one indexed by "unique id", would that solve the issue (ignoring for now the fact that it would double your disk space requirement?)

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner, it would. However if I try to B-Tree the index based on Unique Id, it would take up time as I would need to actively sort the index every time a change happen on the database. And there are "-100 to LONG_MIN" available unique ids any of the 64million records can be assigned to. This means if will do the same approach to RecNum indexes, the file would be (ABS(LONG_MIN) * 24 bytes) - 100 * 24 bytes) for the Unique Id based index, roughly 50GB, if I wont sort actively.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd need to re-sort the index -- AFAIK B-Trees keep their data in sorted order at all times.  Do you mean that the O(log N) overhead of inserting and deleting nodes in the B-Tree is too high?

As for the 50GB size, surely that's only the theoretical worst-case scenario, i.e. your index will only include records for IDs that are actually in use and not every possible ID at all times?  (Assuming that's so, then it probably doesn't matter since in that scenario your main database will have blown up before then anyway?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple: Do not try to reinvent the wheel.

Any full SQL database out there is easily capable of storing and indexing tables with several million entries.

For a large table you would commonly use a B+Tree. You don't need to balance the tree on every insert, only when a node exceeds the minimum or maximum size. This gives a bad worst case runtime, but the cost is amortized.

There is also a lot of logic involved in efficiently, dynamically caching and evicting parts of the index in memory. I strongly advise against trying to re-implement all of that on your own.